# Why boolean modifier not working

Tags: modifiers

Im using a boolean modifier and the face are correct yet the difference operation not working on it. Im making 2017 and i want to cut the 0 with the shape as u can notice in the image and blend file attach. Plz let me know whats wrong with my model[image]
[image]

Comment: I have changed the Solver to Carve (in the Boolean modifier settings ) and now it works. But I don't know why it doesn't work with BMesh, sorry.
I think this type of model could be easier to make by drawing its shape from the top view (using curves for example) and extruding it.

Comment: But it did not cut all the way making a hole just the upper part is cut

Comment: You should clean up your 2017 mesh first. There's ~294 doubled vertices. If you delete the '0' upper and lower faces, recreate as ngons, then boolean 'cut', it cleanly punches out the middle.

Comment: @JanKadeřábek yes ur right the carve is working not the mesh and why there is negative vote may i know reason

Comment: "Fix my blend" questions are frowned upon here because they are of little use to future readers. Instead, well-developed, general questions apply to many situations and are far more useful.

Comment: While I didn't downvote, one more possible reason is that this question was asked a lot times before. With the culprit - *do not use Ngons and double vertices with Boolean*. Those are generally bad things, but they are even worse when combined together with Boolean.

Comment: @MrZak thanks u not downvote but the reason here is removing double and its cutting with carve and not with mesh why. whats the reason behind it

Comment: The reason for why it's not working is already stated above by @Leorex and me -  doubles and Ngons (faces with > 4 verts). Remove them, then recreate new ones / fill with quads. Then BMesh will work as well as Carve.

Answer (score 2):

The blend file provided has already had some Boolean operations applied. Both the *2017* and *cut* meshes have some doubled vertices and the *0* has overlapping faces.

You should always **ensure clean meshes before you attempt Boolean operations**.

[image: Unclean mesh - doubled vertices]

By deleting *0*'s upper and lower faces, removing both meshes' doubled vertices ( Mesh > Vertices > Remove Doubles ), then recreating the upper and lower faces, the Boolean operation is applied cleanly. The convex ngon works fine in this particular case.

**Don't forget to hide the target Boolean object** to see the results.

[image: clean mesh, clean Boolean operation]